# jdeps returns "not found"

Tags: java, java-11, jdeps

I'm following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/hotels-com-technology/honey-i-shrank-the-java-image-9f737aef8963) which tries to minimize the JVM memory footprint by building a minimal JVM.

When I'm running `jdeps -s myjar.jar` I'm getting:

```
myjar.jar -> java.base
myjar.jar -> java.logging
myjar.jar -> not found
```

In the tutorial he solves this by running another command.

```
jdeps -cp 'lib/*' -recursive -s myjar.jar
```

I tried this but I'm getting the same result.

How to run it correctly?

Comment: Is `lib` an actual directory with your dependencies?

Comment: No. That's why I'm asking what should I do instead. It's a maven project

Comment: How about [maven-jdeps-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jdeps-plugin/)? Can you try it?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov, I'll try thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a Maven project, you can do it like this:

1. Run `mvn dependency:build-classpath`
2. Copy the output of the maven-dependency-plugin (the line after "Dependencies classpath:")
3. Run `jdeps -cp <paste output here> -s -recursive myjar.jar`

Comment: after running the steps I see that from some dependencies not found still exists: spring-boot-2.4.0.jar -> java.base spring-boot-2.4.0.jar -> java.desktop spring-boot-2.4.0.jar -> java.management spring-boot-2.4.0.jar -> java.xml spring-boot-2.4.0.jar -> not found. what does this means?

Comment: Output is too big, cmd do not accept to paste it

Comment: @FARS How about Powershell? Can you try from there? Also, you can do it from Linux

Answer (score 1):

It is due to **Bug** in Jdeps and has been the same since JDK 8 at least.

You can see the actual Path parser checks if the -cp/-classpath argument list contains **"dir/.*"** format and **not "dir/*"** format as advertised by the docs, examples and the API's javadoc.

[JdepsConfiguration.java:599](https://github.com/adoptium/jdk11u/blob/ebac392d65ab085369ae1b33cc7601d574778d0f/src/jdk.jdeps/share/classes/com/sun/tools/jdeps/JdepsConfiguration.java#L599)

[image]